# "DB Error: no database selected in unknown" when trying to upgrade Civicrm

Tags: upgrade, civicrm-home

I'm on wordpress 6.0, linux, upgrading from CiviCRM 5.36.0 to 5.50.3.

When I try and run the upgrade script i.e. wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fupgrade&reset=1

I get the following error in my debug and it crashes:

```
[22-Jun-2022 19:05:42 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught <table style="border: 1px" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td colspan="3" style="background: #ff9999"> <b>PEAR_Exception</b>: DB Error: no database selected in <b>/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php</b> on line <b>922</b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="background: #ff9999">- <b>DB_Error</b>: DB Error: no database selected in <b>unknown</b> on line <b>unknown</b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="background-color: #aaaaaa; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Exception trace</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: center; background: #cccccc; width:20px; font-weight: bold;">#</td><td style="text-align: center; background: #cccccc; font-weight: bold;">Function</td><td style="text-align: center; background: #cccccc; font-weight: bold;">Location</td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align: center;">0</td><td>CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler()</td><td>/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php:922</td></tr>
<tr in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 955

Jun 22 20:55:26  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(PEAR_Exception))
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#3 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#4 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#7 {main}


Jun 22 20:55:28  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -14
    [message] => DB Error: no database selected
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT * 
 FROM   `civicrm_component`   
 
 
 
 
 
 [nativecode=2006 ** MySQL server has gone away]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT * 
 FROM   `civicrm_component`   
 
 
 
 
 
 [nativecode=2006 ** MySQL server has gone away]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no database selected" code=-14 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT * 
 FROM   `civicrm_component`   
 
 
 
 
 
 [nativecode=2006 ** MySQL server has gone away]"]
)


Jun 22 20:56:14  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(954): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no database selected", -14, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT * \n FROM   `civicrm_component`   \n \n \n \n \n \n [nativecode=2006 *...")
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-14, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT * \n FROM   `civicrm_component`   \n \n \n \n \n \n [nativecode=2006 *...")
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -14, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT * \n FROM   `civicrm_component`   \n \n \n \n \n \n [nativecode=2006 *...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-14, NULL, NULL, "SELECT * \n FROM   `civicrm_component`   \n \n \n \n \n \n [nativecode=2006 *...", "2006 ** MySQL server has gone away")
#7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(391): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError(-14)
#8 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1234): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT * \n FROM   `civicrm_component`   \n \n \n \n \n \n")
#9 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("SELECT * \n FROM   `civicrm_component`   \n \n \n \n \n \n")
#10 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(451): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT * \n FROM   `civicrm_component`   \n \n \n \n \n \n")
#11 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Component.php(74): DB_DataObject->find(FALSE)
#12 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Component.php(37): CRM_Core_Component::getComponents()
#13 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Component.php(116): CRM_Core_Component::_info(FALSE)
#14 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/includes/civicrm-admin-utilities-single.php(2269): CRM_Core_Component::getEnabledComponents()
#15 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_Admin_Utilities_Single->shortcuts_menu_add(Object(WP_Admin_Bar))
#16 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#17 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(524): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#18 /var/www/html/wp-includes/admin-bar.php(95): do_action_ref_array("admin_bar_menu", (Array:1))
#19 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): wp_admin_bar_render("")
#20 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#21 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#22 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin-header.php(267): do_action("in_admin_header")
#23 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php(312): require_once("/var/www/html/wp-admin/admin-header.php")
#24 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(202): CRM_Utils_System_Base->theme("<div id=\"crm-container\" class=\"crm-container\" lang=\"en\" xml:lang=\"en\"...", FALSE, FALSE)
#25 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(452): CRM_Utils_System::theme("<div id=\"crm-container\" class=\"crm-container\" lang=\"en\" xml:lang=\"en\"...")
#26 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(PEAR_Exception))
#27 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#28 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#29 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#30 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#31 /var/www/html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
```

any ideas?

Comment: Here is the entire backtrace:

Comment: Would really appreciated some suggestions, I have no idea what to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that MySQL has crashed.  Check your MySQL log for details, and considering increasing the number of open connections.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, then I noticed this odd error in the MySQL logs:   [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 32 bytes)
I certainly have 32 bytes free.  Have  been monitoring and plenty of free memory, no swapping happening.

Comment: @DanJacobs That error indicates that MySQL wanted 32 bytes more than it had available.  Check `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and files in `/etc/mysql/conf.d` for your MySQL settings (this is Debian/Ubuntu, not sure about other OSes/distros).  Is this an old server?  I see issues like this when I upgrade the OS but don't take the new default settings for MySQL and keep the old ones.  "Reasonable" defaults for memory allocation have changed over time - and it sounds like you can spare more RAM to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, I had already massively upped the defaults.  Didn't work.

Comment: upgraded the server to 4gb RAM and changed innodb_buffer_pool_size to 3G.  Same problem.

Comment: ok, after upgrading the RAM and doing some more tuning of MySQL, I got the same error but also an error saying a table was corrupt (wordpress.log_civicrm_msg_template).  I turned off logging and dropped the table.  Now the upgrade has started to run!

Comment: @DanJacobs Very glad to hear it!  Note that "massively upping the defaults" is actually the *cause* rather than *solution* to MySQL issues - which you probably learned today. e.g. increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size is good for performance, but if you let MySQL allocate more RAM than there is available, you get an out-of-memory error.  OOM errors generally require you lower the RAM allocations